# "she was already foresworn" - meaning in a snippet from a book

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a story by A. Blackwood, I struggle with the meaning of the word "foresworn":

> It was love, perhaps, that carried and interpreted thus the
> instantaneous wireless message—the love that lay undelivered in my
> heart, as in her own, and, since she was foresworn already, lay
> unrecognized.

From the context, I would expect it to be something like "promised to someone else", but no dictionary I consulted offered a meaning like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She was *renounced* ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/forswear#English)) — the narrator had decided not to pursue her. Compare "swear off of" — to put entirely out of one's life.

The "e" in "foreswear" is an unfortunate etymological inconsistency. Unlike "forego/forgo" and "forebear/forbear", where it distinguishes antecedence from absence, here it seems to contribute nothing. I prefer the spelling without "e" to better align with the other words that use the morpheme.